# Not able to assign a variable outside promise in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
 self.getDocumentCount().then(function (text) {
        var stringArray = text.split("(");
        count = stringArray[0].trim();
    }).then(function () {
        self.logger.info("Document text : " + count, self);
    });
    self.logger.info("Checking the count again : " + count, self);
```

I am not able to get value outside promise . i.e the last count variable in code snippet

I am using protractor+javascript+jasmine

Comment: `getDocumentCount()` What is the output of this ? I mean console.log(text) is giving you what output?

Comment: console.log(text) inside promise gives me the count of documents(i.e is required result). if I try to fetch the same value outside promise I am getting undefined

Comment: So can't you store the result there itself  which is returned from a promise?

Comment: No, That is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
var tempObject = {}

it('should get count', function() {
      getDocumentCount(strDoc);
});

it('should display count', function() {
      console.log(tempObject.Count);
});

function = getDocumentCount(text) {
    var stringArray = text.split("(");
    tempObject.Count = stringArray[0].trim();
})
```

Comment: Could you please provide me more info on tempObject

Comment: tempObject is an array variable in the sample code.  
But you can also use a normal variable if you like.